# Enabling debugging in gruntjs for Angular

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

Folks,

I just started using grunt to compile my angular application. However what I noticed now is that my browser no longer gives me the location of the exact error in the exact file.

What do I need to do in grunt to overcome this ?

grunt.js posted below :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-recess');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html2js');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint','build','karma:unit']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean','html2js','concat','recess:build','copy:assets','copy:styleguide' ]);
  grunt.registerTask('release', ['clean','html2js','uglify','jshint','karma:unit','concat:index', 'recess:min','copy:assets','copy:styleguide']);
  grunt.registerTask('test-watch', ['karma:watch']);

  // Print a timestamp (useful for when watching)
  grunt.registerTask('timestamp', function() {
    grunt.log.subhead(Date());
  });

  var karmaConfig = function(configFile, customOptions) {
    var options = { configFile: configFile, keepalive: true };
    var travisOptions = process.env.TRAVIS && { browsers: ['Firefox'], reporters: 'dots' };
    return grunt.util._.extend(options, customOptions, travisOptions);
  };

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    distdir: 'dist',
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    banner:
    '/*! <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
    '<%= pkg.homepage ? " * " + pkg.homepage + "\\n" : "" %>' +
    ' * Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author %>;\n' +
    ' * Licensed <%= _.pluck(pkg.licenses, "type").join(", ") %>\n */\n',
    src: {
      js: ['src/**/*.js', '<%= distdir %>/templates/**/*.js'],
      specs: ['test/**/*.spec.js'],
      scenarios: ['test/**/*.scenario.js'],
      html: ['src/index.html'],
      tpl: {
        app: ['src/app/**/*.tpl.html'],
        common: ['src/common/**/*.tpl.html']
      },
      less: ['src/less/stylesheet.less'], // recess:build doesn't accept ** in its file patterns
      lessWatch: ['src/less/**/*.less']
    },
    clean: ['<%= distdir %>/*'],
    copy: {
      assets: {
        files: [
          { dest: '<%= distdir %>', src : '**', expand: true, cwd: 'src/assets/' }
        ]
      },
      styleguide: {
        files: [
          { dest: '<%= distdir %>/style-guide', expand: true, src: '**', cwd: 'src/less/easyS/style-guide-v49634/fonts' },
          { dest: '<%= distdir %>/style-guide', expand: true, src: '**', cwd: 'src/less/easyS/style-guide-v49634/images' }
        ]
      }
    },
    karma: {
      unit: { options: karmaConfig('test/config/unit.js') },
      watch: { options: karmaConfig('test/config/unit.js', { singleRun:false, autoWatch: true}) }
    },
    html2js: {
      app: {
        options: {
          base: 'src/app'
        },
        src: ['<%= src.tpl.app %>'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/templates/app.js',
        module: 'templates.app'
      },
      common: {
        options: {
          base: 'src/common'
        },
        src: ['<%= src.tpl.common %>'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/templates/common.js',
        module: 'templates.common'
      }
    },
    concat:{
      dist:{
        options: {
          banner: "<%= banner %>"
        },
        src:['<%= src.js %>'],
        dest:'<%= distdir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      },
      index: {
        src: ['src/index.html'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/index.html',
        options: {
          process: true
        }
      },
      angular: {
        src:['external/angular/angular.js','external/angular/angular-*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/angular.js'
      },
      bootstrap: {
        src:['external/angular-ui/bootstrap/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/bootstrap.js'
      },
      jquery: {
        src:['external/jquery/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/jquery.js'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist:{
        options: {
          banner: "<%= banner %>"
        },
        src:['<%= src.js %>'],
        dest:'<%= distdir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      },
      angular: {
        src:['<%= concat.angular.src %>'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/angular.js'
      },
      bootstrap: {
        src:['external/angular-ui/bootstrap/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/bootstrap.js'
      },
      jquery: {
        src:['external/jquery/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/jquery.js'
      }
    },
    recess: {
      build: {
        files: {
          '<%= distdir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.css':
          ['<%= src.less %>'] },
        options: {
          compile: true
        }
      },
      min: {
        files: {
          '<%= distdir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.css': ['<%= src.less %>']
        },
        options: {
          compress: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch:{
      all: {
        files:['<%= src.js %>', '<%= src.specs %>', '<%= src.lessWatch %>', '<%= src.tpl.app %>', '<%= src.tpl.common %>', '<%= src.html %>'],
        tasks:['default','timestamp']
      },
      build: {
        files:['<%= src.js %>', '<%= src.specs %>', '<%= src.lessWatch %>', '<%= src.tpl.app %>', '<%= src.tpl.common %>', '<%= src.html %>'],
        tasks:['build','timestamp']
      }
    },
    jshint:{
      files:['gruntFile.js', '<%= src.js %>', '<%= src.specs %>', '<%= src.scenarios %>'],
      options:{
        curly:true,
        eqeqeq:true,
        immed:true,
        latedef:true,
        newcap:true,
        noarg:true,
        sub:true,
        boss:true,
        eqnull:true,
        globals:{}
      }
    }
  });

};
```

Comment: Can you please post your Grunt config?

Comment: How were you previously running your application? It is the concat task that is munching all your files together. But I'm not sure how you were getting those dependencies into your app before concatenating them with grunt.

Comment: What does it give you instead?  It should still point to the line and location of the error in the minified js file, correct?